# What do all those dollar sign definitions mean in Loopback's Access control? Like $everyone, $unauthenticated, etc

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm reading Access control concepts of Loopback (https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Controlling+data+access).

There is a text:

[image]

What do all those dollar sign `$everyone`, `$unauthenticated`, etc. mean? These variables (are they variables or what are they?) are not present in the source code in the example they provide https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-access-control. And they do not make an attempt to explain the meaning of them in docs.

Answer (score 0):

`$everyone`, `$unauthenticated`, `$authenticated` and `$owner` are predefined roles in Loopback used in acls for access control to rest endpoints.

And these are used in the project, you have mentioned in `common/models/project.json`. When you run the project you can see rest endpoints with:

- `$everyone` acl: can be used by anyone accessing the project.
- `$authenticated` acl: can be used by only logged in user.
- `$owner` acl: can be used by logged in user with access permission on any project instance.

Now there are also custom roles used in the project like `admin`, `teamMember` which can be created specific to your project.

Since `$everyone`, `$unauthenticated`, `$authenticated` and `$owner` are generic and can be common to all the projects. Hence, are predefined in Loopback.